# How to unique and sum ‘3rd‘ by same '1rd,2rd' of array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

target data form is (x,y,count).

```
[[   0  100    1]
 [   2  200    1]
 [   4  300    1]
 ]
```

I have many points with (x,y) .And using below code to count points, geting (x,y,z)

```
unique, counts = np.unique(data, axis=0, return_counts=True)
new_point_count = np.column_stack((unique, counts))
```

Now, I have different data. How to sum different data by python or numpy?

```
[[   0  100    1]
 [   2  200    3]
 [   4  400    1]
 ]

[[   1  100    1]
 [   2  200    10]
 [   3  300    5]
 ]
```

result

```
[[   0  100    1]
 [   1  100    1]
 [   2  200    13]
 [   3  300    5]
 [   4  400    1]
 ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.unique` one more time:

```
# Example
a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (4, 3))
b = np.random.randint(0, 4, (4, 3))
a
# array([[1, 3, 3],
#        [3, 0, 2],    <--
#        [2, 3, 1],
#        [3, 3, 0]])
b
# array([[3, 1, 0],
#        [3, 0, 3],    <-- 
#        [0, 1, 3],
#        [0, 3, 2]])

# combine
ab = np.r_[a, b]
# find uniques and label original data with index of their unique
unq, inv = np.unique(ab[:, :-1], axis=0, return_inverse=True)
# sum counts by index
np.c_[unq, np.bincount(inv, ab[:, -1]).astype(int)]
# array([[0, 1, 3],
#        [0, 3, 2],
#        [1, 3, 3],
#        [2, 3, 1],
#        [3, 0, 5],    <--
#        [3, 1, 0],
#        [3, 3, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a set of data arrays **{a1, a2, ... , an}** .

You can simply stack you arrays vertical before calling 'unique' function.

```
SIZE = 10**6
a1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, (SIZE, 2))
a2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, (SIZE, 2))
c = np.vstack([a1, a2]) # a1, a2, ... - you data arrays 
unique, counts = np.unique(c, axis=0, return_counts=True)
new_point_count = np.column_stack((unique, counts))
```

Comment: thanks.But I have different raw data, each data (x,y) is uniqued to a new (x,y,count). So I need to sum (x,y,count).